# Win10 1803 not asking for WiFi connection during OSD

Tags: windows-10, sccm-2012-r2

So, we have a Win10 task sequence that I'm trying to update to 1803. However, the task sequence was designed specifically for offline use (including Offline Domain Join). The thing is, prior to 1703, it worked fine. However, after 1703, it stopped asking for a WiFi connection. So when it's plugged into ethernet, it works fine, but if not, then it fails to download the ODJ file, so it can't complete the ODJ, so the Enable BitLocker step fails because it can't communicate with AD to upload the recovery key.

To try to force it to prompt for a WiFi connection I'm applying an unattend.xml during the task sequence. I know that the HideWirelessSetupInOOBE is supposed to have been deprecated several versions back, but other people have said it worked for them. It hasn't for me though. But, just in case, here's the contents of my unattend.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="x64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <OOBE>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <HideLocalAccountScreen>true</HideLocalAccountScreen>
                <HideOEMRegistrationScreen>true</HideOEMRegistrationScreen>
                <HideOnlineAccountScreens>true</HideOnlineAccountScreens>
                <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>false</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
                <NetworkLocation>Work</NetworkLocation>
                <ProtectYourPC>1</ProtectYourPC>
                <SkipMachineOOBE>false</SkipMachineOOBE>
                <SkipUserOOBE>false</SkipUserOOBE>
            </OOBE>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="wim:c:/temp/install.wim#Windows 10 Enterprise Evaluation" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

I'm at kind of a loss here, because without this functionality, this TS is severely ham-stringed. We have a large consultant fleet who are rarely in the office, and periodically need to re-image their laptops at a client site, or a hotel, or their house, or whatever. So manually adding a WiFi connection via the task sequence is also out of the question.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I can try?

Comment: Check the contents of \windows\panther\unattend.xml. It will show you what windows really used for the unattend file. Please specify how you created the task sequence. Is this a MDT deployment? I’m not familiar with remote or offline deployments, but the unattend file is usually modified and injected during deployment by the task sequence.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I specified it, but obviously not. This is a SCCM task sequence, not MDT. And the unattend.xml is being used via an option in the task sequence itself, so I'm not seeing it in \windows\panther. I'm not sure if I should be?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after numerous months of trying to get this working, I'm giving up. I'm adding instructions to make sure people are plugged into Ethernet during the imaging process, and forgetting about Wi-fi.

Answer (score 0):

In the windows folder for both the target image and winPE image, you will need to create cmd files that have something like set /p new_variable="type the SSID of the network: "

and one for the password. This page has the commands necessary for connecting via commandline to wifi networks: https://www.techworm.net/2016/10/connect-manage-delete-wi-fi-networks-using-command-prompt.html

Use unattend runasynchronous tags to run the cmd file or files. The end user should be prompted to type the name of the network, then the wifi key, once it is done. For hotels where you need to open a special permissions web page, I cannot help you, but sounds like a good challenge.

You can also add .net 4.5 support to the wims and try using the wirelessconnect program mentioned on this page: http://www.scconfigmgr.com/2018/03/06/build-a-winpe-with-wireless-support/

Have to scroll down a bit to see where he employs it. I myself got wireless going, but it was with a static network. Hope you take this up again.